# Differences between GNU C++ and Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, g++

What are the differences between GNU C++ 4.3 and MSVC++ 10? I am talking about language features and standards compliance.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. What versions are you asking about?

Comment: @Gabe You can consider the latest versions.

Comment: Gulshan: "latest" is always changing. Compilers are always coming out with new features and standards are continuously evolving. Please specify versions or the question won't be valid.

Comment: @Gabe GNU 4.3+ (latest is 4.5.2) and MSVC++10

Answer (score 5):

Here are two pages that might be of help:

1. [Options controlling C++ dialect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) (GNU C++)
2. [Standards compliance issues in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tb15w2z%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Microsoft C++)

Search for keyword "standard" in first link, this will show you which options break standards compliance. Second link is fairly self explanatory, but this is the 2003 version. It's possible that more standards (non)compliance has been built in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

Language features are formed by compiler because they are implemented into compiler.

So when you're talking about differences in implementations - you're talking about differences in compilers. There are no differences in implementations without compilers.

Comment: a valid remark, however maybe more suitable as comment to the Q.

Comment: @Gulshan: My comment is not regarding your question, it's a comment for abatishchev's answer.

Comment: @sharkin Soo sorry. I mistakenly addressed you.

Comment: I wanted to ommit the compiler options like "this compiler does this and that one doesn't support that". So, I stated about language features. I think, there ARE differences in implementations without compilers. That is the features. Anyway. Maybe you have got what I want. So, please answer if you know.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think the language features would be awfully different. I mean the language remains the same. The difference would be in the libraries that are available with each implementation. VC++ comes with loads to work on Windows platform and is the preferred choice for it.

Comment: -1, language featuers and compliance can indeed differ between implementations. E.g. vc++'s earlier for-loop scope, or built-in unicode types.

Comment: Awesome. Just in case you missed it I said I don't "THINK". Which means I'm making a guess here. I don't think I gave a wrong answer but it's how I think it may be. So, you need to read before clicking the tempting down vote button. Also I said they wouldn't be awfully different, I'm sure you think one is closer to LISP and other to HASKELL isn't it???

Comment: @Sidharth: Regardless, voting should show future readers the quality of the answer. Since your answer is wrong (or subjective at best), it should be downvoted to point out that it may be misleading info, this is how SO works. It has nothing to do with your intentions.

Comment: The answer was neither wrong nor misleading. Sure people who're slow won't be able to comprehend that I'm not conclusive but the majority will. Any you can downvote all you want. That doesn't make "this is how SO works" any more valid.

Comment: @Sidharth: It's not my ambition to degrade your effort to express an opinion or even making guesses. However, SO is not the place for this since it's not a regular forum like we're used to. It (intentionally) lacks proper facilities for discussion. It's just questions and answers, and voting to point out relevance, quality and correctness. So if you like, disregarding all said, the bottom line is that your post doesn't answer the Q.

Comment: I'm not concerned with your ambitions or lackof. And the bottom line is that I've given a constructive suggestion which is "NOT" wrong (I've written the implementations will not be extremely dissimilar which is spot on, despite what you'd say about a for loop) and you've given a monologue on how SO should run. Go figure.

Comment: The answer is actually wrong, there are big important differences between GCC and Microsoft Compiler. For example the default constructor for integers in Microsoft Compiler does nothing, i.e. leaves memory garbage on the variable, this causes hard to debug unexpected problems. And SO is not a conversation forum, if the answer is not useful it should not be upvoted and if it is missleading it should be downvoted.